# Python string formatting: reference one argument multiple times

Tags: python, string-formatting

If I have a string like:

```
"{0} {1} {1}" % ("foo", "bar")
```

and I want:

```
"foo bar bar"
```

What do the replacement tokens have to be? (I know that my example above is incorrect; I'm just trying to express my goal.)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
"{0} {1} {1}".format("foo", "bar")
```

Comment: Interesting. Why does that work with `"str".format(args)` but not `"str" % args`?

Comment: @Rosarch: Because the `{n}` syntax only works for `str.format()`, not `str.__mod__()`.

Comment: @Rosarch: i guess you have mixed the new way with the old way of formating because the old way don't use `{}` as a place holders :), but using the `.format()` is the new way of formating strings take a look at the pep 3101 for more detail : http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

Comment: Could you pass more than one value to `{0}`? For example, if you have two instances of `{0}` in a string, but you want to pass two different strings for each one?

Answer (score 16):

```
"%(foo)s %(foo)s %(bar)s" % { "foo" : "foo", "bar":"bar"}
```

is another true but long answer. Just to show you another viewpoint about the issue ;)

Comment: +1 because I didn't know you could do this, and I prefer the readability

Answer (score 8):

Python 3 has exactly that syntax, except the `%` operator is now the `format` method. `str.format` has also been added to Python 2.6+ to smooth the transition to Python 3. See [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more details.

```
>>> '{0} {1} {1}' % ('foo', 'bar')
'foo bar bar'
```

It cannot be done with a tuple in older versions of Python, though. You can get close by using mapping keys enclosed in parentheses. With mapping keys the format values must be passed in as a dict instead of a tuple.

```
>>> '%(0)s %(1)s %(1)s' % {'0': 'foo', '1': 'bar'}
'foo bar bar'
```

From the [Python manual](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

> When the right argument is a dictionary (or other mapping type), then the formats in the string must include a parenthesised mapping key into that dictionary inserted immediately after the '%' character. The mapping key selects the value to be formatted from the mapping.